# Correspondence between Dirichlet characters and intermediate fields

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, characters, cyclotomic-fields

I am studying from Lawrence C. Washington's book Introduction to cyclotomic field. In chapter 3 I have a group of Dirichlet characters $X$ modulo $n$ (characters of $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})\cong (\mathbb{Z}_n/\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$), then I want to prove $(X^{\perp})^{\perp}=X$, where $X^{\perp}$ consists of $\sigma \in \textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$, for which $\chi(\sigma)=1, \forall \chi \in X$, and $ (X^{\perp})^{\perp}$ consists of all $\chi$, for which $\chi(\sigma)=1, \forall \sigma \in X^{\perp}$. Thank you.

Comment: This is actually a general property in the duality theory for finite abelian groups. It is even proved in detail in Washington's chapter on Dirichlet characters, propos. 3.4. What is your point ?

Comment: But in 3.4 you go from subgroup to characters then to group again and I need characters to subgroup then to characters

Comment: This is just a question of notations. If X is the group of characters of the Galois group (written G), then X = G^ in the notations just before 3.1, and X^= G^^$\cong$G by 3.2, thus G is the group of characters of X, i.e. G and X play exactly symmetrical roles. It is perhaps more suggestive to write the dualities as a symmetric bilinear form  $G \times X \to C^*, (\sigma , \chi) \to < \sigma, \chi>:= \chi (\sigma)$, and similarly when  exchanging X and G. Just as in 3.3, the orthogonal  of X consists of the $\sigma \in X^ = G$ s.t. $\chi (\sigma)=1$ for all $\chi$ in X, and you can apply 3.4.